# UIView Shadow Gradient

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient, shadow

I have created a custom UIView in my iOS project that has a drop shadow.
My aim is to apply the same gradient to the shadow as it is on the view's background.

Below is an example of how my current solid colour shadows look.

[image: Shadow Example]
This is done through a subclass of UIView with the below code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowX, height: shadowY)
    layer.shadowRadius = shadowBlur
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1

    let inset: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.05
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: 0.0), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
}
```

I have been playing around with creating a second gradient layer and masking it to the shadow but have had no luck. Please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't do more with standard CALayer shadow.
Take a look at **filters** property of CALayer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters

Create second **CAGradientLayer** and apply a **GausianBlur** filter for example.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGaussianBlur

Disable standard layer shadows and add your blurred layer as sublayer.

Answer (score 1):

Use my code for your requirement available in my gitRepo https://github.com/Krishnarjun-Banoth/BlurView/tree/master/Shadows

Step1: Just drag and drop **BlurEffect.swift** file in your project.

Step2: Then simply Use below View extension methods for each one your views individually.

```
  testView.applyGradient(colours: [UIColor.blue,UIColor.orange]) //pass your required colours.
  testView.blur(blurRadius: 5.0)
```

Note: Inspired from @Jacek Głazik answer and FlexMonkey's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @jacek is right, you're pushing the limit of what you can do with `CALayer` shadows (which isn't much to be honest)

The best things to do as jacek explain is to create your own shadow, though another `CAGradientLayer` applying Gaussian blur to act as a shadow.

Also, I don't believe placing your code inside the `layoutSubviews` is the most appropriate place. Once configured your layer won't need to change much, and thus it will be called a lot if your layout change a lot.

Usually if using a view coming from interface-builder, I would call this logic from `awakeFromNib` inside a dedicated `configureBackgroundViews` function for example.